# Find all integers $x$ so that there is an integer y so that ${x\choose y} = 1999000$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> (HMMT 2000 Guts round #45). Find all integers $x$ so that there is an integer y so that ${x\choose y} = 1999000$.

> The point of this question is to better understand a post on AoPs. I'm not even sure if the post is entirely correct. I'd say the main point I don't get is why we can't have $y> 1999$. I don't quite understand why their use of Bertrand's postulate works, since it might not ensure there is a prime exceeding y between $x-y+1$ and $x$. The Sylvester-Schur theorem mentioned below can be used to ensure this, but I don't think it is necessary.

I checked out the solution [here at AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c129h611421p3635177).

> Is there a way to shorten the solution on AoPs that avoids using Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What's the question?  For integers, it is certainly true that $x-y+1>y\implies x>2y-1\implies x≥2y$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity, as it stands, it is hard to sort out what you  are asking.  I note that the solution you link to does not appear to mention the Sylvester-Shur Theorem so it's not clear to me why you are bringing it up.  Are you proposing an alternate argument?  Something else?

Comment: I've edited in better MathJax and better flow, but I can't edit in context or a question for you. Are you simply trying to determine the answer to the original question? Are you trying to understand the AOPS solution better? What does the Sylvester-Shur theorem have to do with anything?

Comment: @lulu is the question more clear now? I don't know why it was confusing in the first place; I was just asking a question to better understand why in the AoPs answer we couldn't have $y >1999.$

Comment: Not really. The application of Bertrand seems clear...it just kills the cases $x≥2y$.  Other cases are handled by other means.

Comment: I asked for clarification, the only other commentator was similarly unable to sort out your post. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: @lulu I still don't understand why the application of Bertrand's postulate is correct.

Comment: They only use Bertrand to exclude the case $x≥2y$ and $y>1999$ and that seems straight forward.  Indeed, if $x≥2y$ then there is a prime $p$ with $1999<y<p<x$ so $p$ divides the numerator of $\binom xy$, a contradiction.  But is that your confusion?  I'd have said that the badly written part was where they reduce to this case.  Lot of hand waving there.

Comment: They seem to be asserting that, if $y>1999$ and $y<x<2y$ that we must have $x-y<1999$ but that is just false.  So, to recap, I'd say that Bertrand does indeed handle the case $y>1999$, $ x≥2y$ but that I don't understand how they handle the case $y>1999, x<2y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To shorten the AOPS answer:

**Claim**: $x = 1999000, x=2000$ are the only solutions.

Set $N = 1999000$ for simplicity. $\binom{N}{1} = N$ and $\binom{2000}{2} = N$ are nearly trivial. Now we show there are no other solutions. We consider three cases:

1. $x<1999$
2. $x = 1999$
3. $x>1999$

For the first case, note that $1999$ is prime. Since $N$ has a factor of $1999$, no binomial coefficient with $x < 1999$ can be equal to $N$, so there are no solutions to the first case.

It's easy to show that $\binom{1999}{3} > N > \binom{1999}{2}$, and thus there are no solutions to the second case.

For the third case: we know the binomial formula. Let's consider what happens if we increase $y$ by $1$ while keeping $N$ constant, and we assume our new $x$ will be $x+n$, and for the moment that $n$ is positive:

$$
\begin{gather}
N = \frac{x!}{y! \cdot (x-y)!} = \frac{(x+n)!}{(y+1)! \cdot (x+n-y-1)!} \\[1ex]
(x+n)! \cdot (x-y)! \cdot y! = x! \cdot (y+1)! \cdot (x+n-y-1)! \\[1ex]
(x+n)(x+n-1)\cdots (x+1) = (y+1) \cdot [(x-y+n-1)(x-y+n-2) \cdots (x-y+1)] \\[1ex]
y+1 = \frac{(x+n)(x+n-1)\cdots(x+1) \color{red}{ \ [n \text{ terms}}]} {(x-y+n-1)(x-y+n-2) \cdots (x-y+1) \color{blue}{ \ [\mathbf{n-1} \text{ terms}}]} \\[1ex]
y+1 = (x+1) \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{x+k}{x+k-y-1}
\end{gather}$$

We know $x > y$ here, meaning that every term in the product is <strike>positive</strike> *greater than zero*, and the product is <strike>positive</strike> *greater than zero* (Man, where was my brain when I wrote this?). But this is a contradiction: the equality can't hold if $x>y$. Hence, $n$ must be negative if we increase $y$ by 1. (Perform the same manipulations with $x-n$ and you get equations that *could* hold.) Because of the symmetry of the binomials, this will be true until $y=x/2$, at which point it $x$ will reach a minimum.

Hence there are no solutions with $x>1999$, and we are done.

Comment: Can you justify the statement "If we increase $y$ while holding $N$ constant, it's clear that $x$ must decrease until $y\ge 2x$"? I think there's a typo there; it should probably be: we must decrease $x$ until $x\ge 2y$ or something.

Comment: @user3379 Agreed, they meant $y\ge\frac{1}{2}x$. By symmetry of the coefficient, we only need to consider $0\le y\le\frac{1}{2}x$ anyway, so we can take $x$ decreasing wlog. $y=2\implies x=2000$, so $y\ge3\implies x\le1999$

Comment: @FShrike I still don't understand. Honestly I was able to understand a lot of nontrivial number theory solutions before, so I don't know what's happening now. Obviously we just need to consider $0\leq y\leq 1/2 x.$ WHY CAN WE TAKE x decreasing WLOG $y=2$? $y=2$ implies (by the "unique lower index" lemma from the aops solution) that $x=2000$. WHY does $y\ge 3$ imply $x\leq 1999$?

Comment: @FShrike also, WHY is the AoPs solution correct in using Bertrand's postulate? I don't know why Bertrand's postulate guarantees that ${x\choose y}$ has a prime factor exceeding $y$ for $x\ge 2y$.

Comment: @user3379 (to the first comment) I meant, we take $x$ decreasing as a function in $y$ wlog. (new sentence) since $y=2$ has $x=2000$, $y\ge3\iff y>2$ must have (by the decreasing property) $x<2000$, i.e. $x\le1999$. (to the second comment) I haven't looked at, and can't confirm the correctness of, the aops solution

Comment: To see why the value of $x$ must decrease, it's clearer to rearrange the equality, consider $x$ as a real function in $y$ and if $y\to y+1$, with a new solution $x'\in\Bbb R$, then: $$x(x-1)\cdots(x-y+1)(y+1)=N(y+1)!=(x')(x'-1)\cdots(x'-y)$$With $\frac{1}{2}x'\ge y$, $\frac{1}{2}x\ge y$. That means: $$\frac{(x')(x'-1)\cdots(x'-y+1)}{x(x-1)\cdots(x-y+1)}=\frac{y+1}{x'-y}\le\frac{y+1}{y+2}<1$$If $x'\ge x$, the LHS is $\ge1$, which is a contradiction. To @Eric, maybe include something like this in your post because it's not as immediate from what you've written ($x$ features on both sides)

Comment: (and if it decreases as $y\to y+1$, it inductively decreases as $y\to y'$ where $y'$ is any integer greater than $y$) (the above comment should read, $\frac{1}{2}x'\ge y+1$)

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for the edit. To the other comments, I'll edit the necessary bits into the original answer.

Comment: I agree with @FShrike. WLOG $y\le x/2$. If $x>1999$ then we have solutions with $y=1$ and with $y=2$. If $2<y\le x/2$ then
$$\binom xy>\binom x2\ge\binom{2000}2.$$ Done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen tbh, I find your last comment the most helpful. Now I'm even more confused by the answer by Eric Snyder, but since I basically understand the question well enough, I guess I'll just accept this. I wish Eric Snyder could've come up with an answer that was easier for me to understand though.

Comment: @user3379 I think that Eric is simply trying to make sense out of the AOPS answer. FWIW I upvoted his answer. After all, that's what the question was about. I added the argument from the comment as an answer, shamelessly picking the key observations from Eric's answer but adding the trivial argument covering the IMHO "easy" case $x\ge2000$.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting my comment to an answer.

The tricky range is when $x<1999$. The key observation, as explained by Eric Snyder, is that as $1999$ is a prime, there are no solutions in this range.

The rest of the possibilities are easier to cover. Without loss of generality we can assume that $2y\le x$. This is because
$$\binom x y=\binom x {x-y}.$$
In other words, the mirror symmetry of Pascal's triangle means that any number in it can be found on the left half. Furthermore, the entries on any row of Pascal's triangle are increasing on the left half: with $0\le y<y'\le x/2$ we have
$$
\binom x y <\binom x {y'}.
$$

Reusing Eric's observation that
$$
\binom {1999}2 < 1999000 <\binom {1999}3
$$
implying that $x=1999$ does not work.

When $x\ge2000$ the key is that we must have $y\le2$. For if $y>2$, then we have
$$
\binom x y> \binom x 2 \ge \binom {2000} 2 =1999000.
$$
That leaves us the solutions
$$
\binom {2000}2=1999000=\binom {1999000}1.
$$